# shell how to cut out part of the string()

Tags: string, shell

I have some strings... some of them have more characters other less.. here some examples.

```
ABC_DEF_GHI_JKL_${COD}_${DATE}
ABC_DEF_${COD}_${DATE}
ABC_${COD}_${DATE}
```

I have to do a function where I have to cut out the ${COD} and one _. so the new strings became

```
ABC_DEF_GHI_JKL_${DATE}
ABC_DEF_${DATE}
ABC_${DATE}
```

where the ${COD} is a number... between 1 and 300. But in the string sometimes have numbers in the middle before the ${COD}.
The only sure part is that the end of them is `_${COD}_${DATE}`
does anyone have an idea how to do it?

Comment: Which shell are you using?

Comment: looks like some work for sed. Since you know how it ends, you can create a pattern that ends like that and remove the extra ${COD}_ part out.

Comment: Some real data examples...  CAO_AUTOMATICO_RELATIVO_MASSIVO_ROBO_FOX_2_20150803   another one   CAO_RJ_FIXA_ABERTURAS_AUTOMATICO_5_20150803

Comment: yes, in shell script.

Answer (score 1):

In POSIX shell, you can use

```
date=${str##*_}
tmp=${str%_$date}
cod=${tmp##*_}
str=${tmp%_$cod}_${date}
```

In `bash` (or another shell supporting similar array syntax), you can use

```
IFS=_ read -a parts <<< "$str"
cod=${parts[${#parts[@]}-2]}
# Or in bash 4.3, cod=${parts[-2]}
str=${str/_$cod_/_/}
```

Comment: I don`t want to get the date or the cod, I want to take out the cod from the name... something like name_cod_date to name_date

Comment: Updated to show how to update `str` once `cod` is found.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sed version:

```
sed -n 's/\(.*\)_\(.*\)_\(.*\)$/\1_\3/p' filename
```

Greedily match the suffix and remove the unwanted part(\2) out in the replacement

Answer (score 0):

Here is a core Unix tools version:

```
in=AAA_BBB_123_654_20151207             # input string
n=`echo $in | grep -o _ | wc -l`        # index of field to remove     (here: 4)
nm1=`expr $n - 1`                       # index before field to remove (here: 3)
np1=`expr $n + 1`                       # index after field to remove  (here: 5)
out=`echo $in | cut -d_ -f-$nm1,$np1-`  # remove n-th field from string
```

Result:

```
echo $out
AAA_BBB_123_20151207
```